# Chrome App onSubmit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a very simple Chrome App. It displays a popup with a search box. Submitting the search box opens my site in a new tab.

The search box is empty by default. When it is empty, clicking submit shouldn't do anything. My popup.html looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
   <title>foo</title>   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
  </head> 
<body>
    <div id="srch">
    <form target="_blank" action="foo.php" method="get" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('box').value.length < 1) return false;">
        <input type="text" id="box" name="foo" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="foo" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open popup.html in a browser, then clicking submit does nothing. But if I open it as the Chrome App, then clicking submit still submits the form, without anything in it. So it seems that the JavaScript is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem in your Script**

Chrome Extensions do not allow inline JS or `<script>` tag in HTML Code, so your code `onsubmit="if`  will not surpass CSP, after Eliminating these i got your script running.

## Sample Demonstration of your code

**manifest.json**

Registered Browser action to manifest file.

```
{
    "name": "chrome-app-onsubmit",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263946/chrome-app-onsubmit",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

Eliminated Inline Script

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
   <title>foo</title>  
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head> 
<body>
    <div id="srch">
       <input type="text" id="box" name="foo" value="" />
        <input type ="submit" id="submit" value="foo" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

Your functionality goes here.

```
function _clickHandler() {
    if (document.getElementById('box').value.length < 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("In Success Handler..");
        //Do Your AJAX Request Call here
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = _clickHandler;
});
```

Check [How to Load an Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) for testing your script.

## Reference

- [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this...different browsers can be picky about javascript formatting...just a thought

```
onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('box').value.length < 1) {return false;};">
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Opening popup.html in Chrome works. But it's when it's opened as the Chrome extension that it doesn't work.